# Why mean value inequality fail in this exercise?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have trouble with the second part of exercise 6.32 in Korner's Companion to Analysis book. He asks to show that $|\theta(b) - \theta(a)| > \|b - a\|$. However, I do not understand which condition of the mean value inequality does not apply (I get $\|D\theta(x)\| \le 1$ on the line connecting $a$ with $b$).

When I perform a direct calculation, I do not obtain the inequality either: $2(\pi - \arccos(-1/(1 + 1/10^2)^{1/2})) = 0.1993$, but $\|(-1,1/10) - (-1, -1/10)\| = 2/10 = 0.2$.

What am I doing wrong or not understanding?

**Exercise 6.32:**

Let $U = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{2} : |x| > 1\} \setminus \{(x,0)^T : x \le 0\}$.

If we take $\theta(x)$ to be the unique solution of

$\cos(\theta(x)) = x/(x^2 + y^2)^{1/2}$,
$\sin(\theta(x)) = y/(x^2 + y^2)^{1/2}$,
$-\pi < \theta < \pi$

For $x = (x, y)^T \in U$, show that $\theta$ is everywhere differentiable in $U$ with $\|D\theta(x)\| < 1 $.

**My answer:** I get $\|D\theta(x)\| = 1/\|x\|$.

Second part:
However, show that if $a = (-1, 1/10)^T$, $b = (-1, -1/10)^T$, then

$|\theta(b) - \theta(a)| > |b - a|$.

Comment: Can you rewrite the definition of $U$ which is confusing as you mix up coordinates and points under the same variable $x$? Thanks.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The segment $[a,b]$ is not included in the open $U$ in which $\theta$ is defined. Hence the mean value inequality can't be applied.

Moreover, you made errors in the computation of the $\theta$.

You have $\theta(a) = - \theta(b) \simeq 3.001$.

Comment: I see, the problem is $\theta$  is not continuous on $L = \{(x,0) : x \le 0 \}$

Comment: It is even worse: it is not **defined** on $L$ if you want $\theta$ to belong in $(-\pi,\pi)$.

Comment: you are right!, thanks for help!